# Can IllegalStateException be thrown by ServiceBusSenderClient.sendMessage() unless we close ServiceBusSenderClient?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, illegalstateexception, servicebus

I'm using ServiceBusSenderClient to send messaged to Azure Service Bus. According to [sdk docs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-messaging-servicebus/7.0.0/com/azure/messaging/servicebus/ServiceBusSenderClient.html#sendMessage-com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusMessage-) ServiceBusSenderClient.sendMessage() will throw `NullPointerException`, `AmqpException`, `ServiceBusException`, and `IllegalStateException`.

I can guarantee that my code will never create a serviceBusMessage with a null value so I can ignore `NullPointerException`. `AmqpException` and `ServiceBusException` will be there and I'm logging that for now as in the below code segment.

But I'm not sure whether it will throw `IllegalStateException` unless I close the ServiceBusSenderClient.

```java
        try {
            serviceBusSenderClient.sendMessage(serviceBusMessage);
        } catch (ServiceBusException e) {
            log.error("Message could not be sent.");
        } catch (AmqpException e) {
            log.error("Message is too large.");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            log.error("Sender client is disposed.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/cfb62ae18de2629220df57a4701330824590c63b/sdk/servicebus/azure-messaging-servicebus/src/main/java/com/azure/messaging/servicebus/ServiceBusSenderClient.java#L168) it will throw `IllegalStateException`

> if sender is already disposed.

If you want to ensure you don't use it after it's been disposed, use scope to ensure it's disposed:

```
using (ServiceBusSenderClient serviceBusSenderClient = new ServiceBusSenderClient())
{
  serviceBusSenderClient.sendMessage(serviceBusMessage);
  ...
}
// serviceBusSenderClient out of scope and disposed
```

if you don't scope it it's up to the garbage collector when it's disposed or you can dispose it yourself but the modern way to do that is to make use of `using`.

Comment: One way to dispose the sender client manually is closing the sender client using `senderClient.close()`. I want to know whether sender client get disposed unless I dispose it thoughtfully.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your comment